# DocuSign workflow - SharePoint Online - Start workflow

Tags: docusignapi

I am new to DocuSign and doing a Proof Of Concept (POC) for DocuSign workflow and SharePoint Online. I tried Google but not able to find desired info. and will really appreciate if find help on following:

1. Can we start a DocuSign workflow automatically? means if we update a
   column / field in document library using SharePoint workflow or Flow
   and wants to start DocuSign work?
2. If yes, can we start a DocuSign workflow using a specifc template?
3. Creating a template for DocuSign workflow requires extra license?
4. Can someone point me to resource that can help?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [DocuSign for Microsoft Flow](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/DocuSign-for-Microsoft-Flow-Overview) documentation.

> With DocuSign for Microsoft Flow, you can create workflows across multiple solutions, such as Dynamics, SharePoint, Office365, OneDrive, Salesforce, and many others without code or complex implementations.

Here is a good [video](https://youtu.be/nxuA8AxE4lI) tutorial on using DocuSign for Microsoft flow.

You will need a DocuSign paid plan to send envelopes using templates. See pricing information [here](https://www.docusign.com/products-and-pricing/api-plans)